# On delete : cascade doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables created like so :

```
Schema::create('educations', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->date('from_date');
    $table->date('to_date');
    $table->string('summary');
    $table->integer('cv_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('cv_id')->references('id')
    ->on('cvs')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And they are linked to another table :

```
Schema::create('cvs', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')
    ->on('students')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->string('summary');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The problem is, whenever i call this line :

```
$student->cv->delete();
```

It will drop the cv but not the other attributes in tables related to it.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Are you using SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. `cascade` means that when you'll detele some CV from `cvs` table, all rows with same `cv_id` will be deleted from `educations` table. You can't expect the whole table will be deleted.

Comment: Sorry that's exactly what i want "all rows with same cv_id will be deleted from educations table". It was hard to explain what i want. It just doesn't work...